# MSYS2, autoconf and SetProcessAffinityMask

Tags: autoconf, msys2, iperf3

I'm trying to compile iperf3 3.6 under MSYS2.
./configure (autoconf) reports `"checking for SetProcessAffinityMask... yes"`, but at compile time I get following related error

```
iperf_api.c:67:10: fatal error: Windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Windows.h>
```

I do not understand how it is possible that during ./configure tests it can detect the presence of SetProcessAffinityMask and during compile is unable.

Comment: What toolchain provided by MSYS2 are you using?  Specifically, can you run `echo $MSYSTEM` and `which gcc` and post the output here?

Comment: I use makepkg to build the package for iperf3.

`$ echo $MSYSTEM
MSYS`
`$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0`

Comment: OK, the MSYS environment you are using is for developing software that runs on top of the POSIX emulation provided by msys-2.0.dll.  This toolchain is not for making native Windows software, so I would not expect `windows.h` to be available or functional.  Some part of the iperf build system or source code has decided to include `windows.h` and that should probably be fixed, or perhaps you should switch to one of the two MinGW environments provided by MSYS2 which can build native Windows software.